# LISP function which, given a number and a list, returns the first even number greater than n

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm having trouble finding my error.
This keeps returning `nil`:

```
(even-greater-n 5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

(defun even-greater-n (n L)
   (cond ((null L) nil)
         ((and (> (car L) n) (evenp n)) (car L))
         (t (even-greater-n n (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: Its because you are checking if `n` is even and in your test it's `5` and never ever even..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your error

You are passing to [`evenp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_evenpc.htm) `n`
instead of `(car L)`.

## Iteration

This is relatively easy to implement using
[`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(defun even-greater (n l)
  (loop for k in l
    when (and (< n k)
              (evenp k))
    return k))

(even-greater 5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
==> 6
```

## Recursion

If you are required to use recursion, you can do it too:

```
(defun even-greater (n l)
  (cond ((endp l) nil)
        ((and (< n (first l))
              (evenp (first l)))
         (first l))
        (t (even-greater n (rest l)))))

(even-greater 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
==> 4
```

## Library

And, of course, Lisp has a very powerful library, including
[`find-if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm):

```
(defun even-greater (n l)
  (find-if (lambda (k)
             (and (< n k)
                  (evenp k)))
           l))

(even-greater 2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
==> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You must look for `(car L)` is even or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find-if` and a single, open-coded lambda function:

```
(defun even-greater (n list)
  (find-if (lambda (item) (and (> item n) (evenp item))) list))
```

Using functional combinators:

```
;; Combine multiple functions with AND:
;; Returns a function of one-argument which
;; passes that argument to the functions in the list,
;; one by one. If any function returns nil, it stops
;; and returns nil. Otherwise it returns the value
;; returned by the last function:
(defun andf (&rest functions)                                               
  (lambda (arg)
    (let (res)
      (dolist (f functions res)
        (unless (setf res (funcall f arg))
          (return))))))

 ;; Returns a one-argument function which tests
 ;; whether its argument is greater than quant.
 (defun greater (quant)
   (lambda (arg) (> arg quant)))

 ;; "find it, if it is greater than n, and even"
 (defun even-greater (n list)                                                
   (find-if (andf (greater n) #'evenp) list))
```